# Is it still possible to obtain a visa on arrival at the Armenian border or must I now have an E-visa?

Tags: visas, borders, australian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, armenia

I'm an Australian citizen and visited Armenia by the land border with Georgia in August or September 2010.

At that time I just paid a few dollars, at the somewhat chaotic border crossing and got a full-page visa in my passport.

But when I look at the [Armenian Ministry of Foreign Affairs page on visas](http://www.mfa.am/en/visa/) they seem to mostly focus on the new [e-visas](https://evisa.mfa.am/pls/dbms/evis_n.put_application_p0), which I don't believe existed at the time of my previous visit.

**So can I still arrive at the border without an e-visa and if so will it affect the length of time I can stay or the amount of the fee I must pay?**

Comment: Not really important, but I got an e-visa on my visit to Armenia in 2003. They've been around for a while.

Comment: The e-visa system was out of order for a while including in 2015, but looks like [it's back online](https://evisa.mfa.am/). If it's down again, a visa on arrival can be done at the border.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mileage varies related to the traveler's nationality, but I entered Armenia from Georgia just three weeks ago and got a 6 euro visa at the border without any problems. I was traveling on a Dutch passport. Danes and Germans crossing the border at the same time as me also easily got their visa at the border for the low price of 6 euros.
The visa fee was payable in Armenian currency only. No ATMs were available, but a change machine was.

I was asked how long i wanted to stay, said about two weeks and got 20 days. I feel I could have gotten longer if I'd ask.

The crossing might have been at Bagramashen, but I'm not totally sure anymore. I took a regular marshrutka from Tbilisi train station to Yerevan.

Comment: Thanks. Do you recall how long your visa was good for, and which border crossing you used? (Add them to your answer rather than a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe It's available ($10) for Australian citizens.

Comment: Any reference as to where you got that info ?